# Configure dwm to automatically open applications

Tags: opensuse, window-manager, dwm

I've just got dwm configured to my liking in terms of colors and tags. I'm just looking for one more thing: the ability to have certain applications automatically start with dwm on certain tags.

For example, I have a `irc` tag, I would like `irssi` to be run in that tag when I start my machine up. Is this possible? What would it look like in `config.h`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

dwm is a minimalist window manager that just manages windows. What you are asking requires a bit of a workaround. There are two separate, but related steps.

First, set up your rules for irrsi in `config.h` - specifying the tag in which you would like it to appear and whether it should be floating or not. Something like this will open `irssi` in the first tag:

```
{ NULL, NULL, "irssi",       1 << 0,       False,       -1 },
```

([explanation of what `1 << 0` means](http://dwm.suckless.org/customisation/tagmask))

If you would like to specify the layout of this tag when dwm opens, you would need to apply the [pertag patch](http://dwm.suckless.org/patches/pertag) and recompile.

The second step is to start the application when you login to X. If you are not using a login manager, you could add an entry to your `~/.xinitrc` - something like:

```
(sleep 5 && xterm -title "irssi" -e irssi ) &
```

The `sleep` is to allow X to start and dwm to load: 5 is ample, you can experiment how little you need...

If you are using a login manager, you will have a `.desktop` file that you can put the commands in.

I prefer a simpler approach using rules and keybinds. So once dwm is open, I just hit, for example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> and `mutt` opens in tag 3.

You can see my `config.h` to get a better idea of how this works:
https://bitbucket.org/jasonwryan/dwm-patchset/src/tip/base.config.customizations

Comment: I remember seeing a pic of a desktop you had ing dwm/tmux. It was really nice (this was a couple months back, I think I emailed you about it). Small world :) Thanks for the link to your dotfile, I'll take a look.

Comment: No problem: have fun with dwm.

Comment: Are you sure it’s `.desktop` and not [`.xprofile`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xprofile)?